# Including directories in urls.py

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django web application, and have created a folder called "issues/" under the "templates/" folder. How do I include ALL files under that directory, without having to make a separate url declaration for each one?

So far, my urls.py file is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'civicate.dev.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^index', 'civicate.dev.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^about', 'civicate.dev.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's URLs don't care in the slightest about templates. If you want to serve HTML files directly, you should configure Apache (or other web server) to do so by bypassing Django. Otherwise, you could write a single view that accepts a slug and renders the relevant template.